# Google Analytics stopped recording traffic all of sudden. Realtime View is not working either

Tags: google-analytics

My website `http://cityful.net/` is not getting traffic for a few days. ON analytics I got the following notification.

[image]

It's been a week since it got a new hit by the crawler. Check Search Console Crawl stats:

**Update**: Realtime View is not working either
[image]

Comment: Did you ever put any filters in place?  Have you checked the "real time" reports in Google Analytics as you browse the site yourself?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Nope. Realtime View is not working either